# Purpose of Thread constructor arguments

Tags: java, multithreading

I found this code on a [tutorial website](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_multithreading.htm):

```
class NewThread implements Runnable {
   Thread t;
   NewThread() {
      // Create a new, second thread
      t = new Thread(this, "Demo Thread");
      System.out.println("Child thread: " + t);
      t.start(); // Start the thread
   }

   // This is the entry point for the second thread.
   public void run() {
      try {
         for(int i = 5; i > 0; i--) {
            System.out.println("Child Thread: " + i);
            // Let the thread sleep for a while.
            Thread.sleep(50);
         }
     } catch (InterruptedException e) {
         System.out.println("Child interrupted.");
     }
     System.out.println("Exiting child thread.");
   }
}

public class ThreadDemo {
   public static void main(String args[]) {
      new NewThread(); // create a new thread
      try {
         for(int i = 5; i > 0; i--) {
           System.out.println("Main Thread: " + i);
           Thread.sleep(100);
         }
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
         System.out.println("Main thread interrupted.");
      }
      System.out.println("Main thread exiting.");
   }
}
```

In the following line, what is the purpose of the arguments, and what is the meaning of `this` in the first argument:

```
 t = new Thread(this, "Demo Thread");
```

Also, what is the expected behaviour (flow) of this code?

Comment: What is your question?  What do you not understand?

Comment: I recommend you to buy some book, "Core Java" is a good choice

Comment: i have black book of java..but i want some coding stuff

Comment: i want to know that ,what is the flow of the program

Comment: I would **NOT** recommend the tutorial site you found this code on. The code is pretty bad, and it's unclear what it is trying to teach, and rest of their tutorials are no better. If you are trying to lean Java, stay away from that site. I recommended a threading tutorial in my answer, and in general [IBM developerWorks](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/) is pretty good.

Comment: @grkvlt sir it  covers only thread part,but what about other topics.Can you tell me which website to approach that can cover all topics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When creating a new `Thread` object you must pass in a `Runnable` object (which does the actual work in its `run()` method) as the first argument to the constructor. The second argument is a name for the thread. So, in your code, the following line in the `NewThread` class constructor:

```
t = new Thread(this, "Demo Thread");
```

Creates a new `Thread` object `t` named *Demo Thread* using itself (an instance of `NewThread`) as the `Runnable` task, since it implements the `Runnable` interface. Then, when `t.start()` is called, the `run()` method of the `NewThread` instance `t` is called.

The API documentation for [*java.lang.Thread*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html) and [*java.lang.Runnable*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html) give more details.

So, your code creates a `NewThread` object, which starts a child thread in the constructor running the *Child Thread* loop, and the *Main Thread* loop is executed by the rest of the code in your `main()` method. I would expect to see output from the child thread interleaved with output from the main thread when this is run.

Also, when catching `InterruptedException` and not re-throwing it, it is good practice to restore the *interrupted* status of the thread, something like this:

```
} catch (InterruptedException ie) {
    System.out.println("Interrupted: " + ie.getMessage());
    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
}
```

This [tutorial](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/tutorials/j-threads/j-threads-pdf.pdf) by Brian Goetz is very good if you want to learn more about Java threading. It's part of an IBM developerWorks [Java concurrency](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/training/kp/j-kp-concurrency/) training module.

Answer (score 0):

The line `t = new Thread(this, "Demo Thread")` is creating a new thread passing the instance of `java.lang.Runnable` that the thread should execute and the name to give the thread (commonly used during logging operations).

It's a bit weird to have the class implementing `java.lang.Runnable` create the thread itself.  Take a look at the examples of how to use threads on the JavaDoc for [java.lang.Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html).

Answer (score 0):

The constructor used in `t = new Thread(this, "Demo thread")` allows to pass a target. The target must be a Runnable. The target's `run()` method will be invoked as a result of starting `t`, so the Thread is created and runs. See the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#Thread%28java.lang.Runnable,%20java.lang.String%29)

Answer (score 0):

That's some seriously messed up code up there. OP, you did not write this, but you'll take heat just for stumbling on it.

First of all: The NewThread is not a thread, it's a Runnable. Not the same thing, and for a reason. But then its **constructor** declares a new thread and **starts it right away**, turning the Runnable into some sort of a Zombie Thread, which defeats the whole purpose of having a Runnable in the first place, and is just a terrible idea, because if you wanted a Thread, you'd declare a Thread, not a Runnable. What if you want to use the Runnable in a ThreadPool? What if you want to define more than one of these Runnables and start them in a orderly fashion? What if the Runnable one day becomes a Callable, where would you see its Future?

Then, to add insult to injury, the code has concurrent code in the main thread. This servers no educational purpose, and has almost no real-life value, because in real life, you normally don't mix threaded code like that, you'd rather have one control thread (main) and 1..n worker threads (controlled by main).

The point of Threads and Runnables is to separate the functional description of the task (that's the Runnable) from the life-cycle behavior (that's the Thread). Parallel execution and scalability is a nice side benefit. So let's refactor the tutorial code to reflect that:

```
class Countdown implements Runnable {

  public void run() {
    try {
      for(int i = 5; i > 0; i--) {
        System.out.println("Child Thread: " + i);
        Thread.sleep(50);
      }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      System.out.println("Child interrupted.");
    }
    System.out.println("Exiting child thread.");
  }
}

public class ThreadDemo2 {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    Thread t = new Thread(new Countdown());
    t.start();
    try {
      for(int i = 5; i > 0; i--) {
        System.out.println("Main Thread: " + i);
        Thread.sleep(100);
      }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      System.out.println("Main thread interrupted.");
    }
    System.out.println("Main thread exiting.");
  }
}
```

That's better. Now the Runnable does no longer pretend to be a Thread, nor does it even care about when or how or by whom it is going to be run. All it does is implement run() which does what the task is supposed to do, and the main thread gives this Runnable as a constructor argument to a new Thread and then start()s it, which in turn means the new Thread will call the Runnable's run(). But we can do better: the two threads do essentially the same thing, so we should implement them that way:

```
class Countdown implements Runnable {
  final String name;
  final int length;
  final int skip;

  public Countdown(String name, int length, int skip) {
    this.name = name;
    this.length = length;
    this.skip = skip;
  }

  public void run() {
    try {
      for(int i = length; i > 0; i--) {
        System.out.println(name + ": " + i);
        Thread.sleep(skip);
      }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      System.out.println(name + " interrupted.");
    }
    System.out.println("Exiting " + name);
  }
}

public class ThreadDemo3 {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    Thread t1 = new Thread(new Countdown("Child One", 5, 50));
    Thread t2 = new Thread(new Countdown("Child Two", 5, 100));
    t1.start();
    t2.start();
  }
}
```

Now we have separated functionality from life-cycle management. Countdown is it's own class which does exactly what the name says and not more, and there is no more worker logic in main. Main just invokes countdowns and starts them.

OP, my biggest advice is: find a better tutorial. The Brian Goetz tutorial mentioned by grkvlt above is **much** better. You might want to invest some money on books by Goetz ("Java Concurrency in Practice") and Doug Lea ("Concurrent Programming in Java"), too.

Comment: Your refactor is definitely much better. I'm not really too sure what the point of the OPs original code was, and I'm not impressed by the site he found it on - the code is lifted from it verbatim, and their other examples aren't any better. I had a quick look at the other 'tutorials' on there, and they are all pretty awful, with typos and mistakes as well as just downright bad practices.